# Does Soundcloud have a Javascript listener for when new data is loaded?

Tags: javascript, listener, soundcloud

Is there anyway to create a Javascript listener for when the Soundcloud API requests more information. I have a frame in which I am using a standard Soundcloud page (like the stream) and was wondering if there is any way to create a Javascript listener to listen for the GET requests when more information is loaded into the frame. When new information is loaded in the frame I want to fire an even in the main page.

I've tried the standard XMLHttpRequest override technique but this didn't seem to work with the frame.

Comment: there's plenty of ways to listen to all sorts of events - what are you trying to achieve though?

Comment: What I want to ultimately achieve to retrieve all the comments that are loaded when a song is. So ideally knowing when a comment is loaded would be best. I think cucko's solution will be enough for me o go off of though.

Comment: Floofer - have you thought of using the API to get the data you're looking for? http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can add event listeners on SC document try with: 
`document.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", callback);`

Comment: It looks like this is exactly what I was looking for. I need to make a few checks each time it happens though so I'm not receiving so many notifications. Thanks!